# Re-Enable ctrl+enter warning in Microsoft Outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut to send emails in Outlook. I have checked the box to "don't show this dialog again". So now, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, the message is sent immediately. Is there any way to re-enable the warning dialog box? So when I will hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> the dialog box will appear forcing me to click on "yes" in "I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut for sending message" dialog box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you 100% sure you saw that dialog box in Outlook 2003? I have never seen and therefore never disabled such a dialog box on my Outlook 2003.

**As far as I know this feature is only available from Outlook 2007 onwards.**

Comment: correct, this function was introduced in Outlook 2007 - see http://blogs.technet.com/b/usefultechnology/archive/2006/04/28/426672.aspx

Comment: @Shevek tx for backing me with technet's authority :)

Comment: This also came on my mind, I am using Outlook 2003 and 2007 (on different computers). As I read the technet blog it seems that this warning message wasn't included in Outlook 2003. But I thought I have checked the box "don't show this dialog again" but it seems that I am wrong. OK. I give up! :) I am sorry for posting stupid questions :) Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: it's not such a stupid question! I use outlook 2010 at home and rely on this function as my thumb tends to linger on the CTRL key far too often. We are only at Outlook 2003 at work and I have sent many an incomplete email...

Comment: At least now I know why I have sometimes sent unfinished e-mails in the past with Outlook 2003. Just disabled Ctrl-Enter with the registry hack as stated in Wessel's answer.

Comment: See this link:

http://www.outlook-tips.net/tips/tip-333-prevent-accidental-sending/

I did not have the Policies key for Outlook on my Windows 7 (Office 2003). I just created a new key (using the .reg file found in the above link), and it got rid of Ctrl+Enter feature.

Answer (score 4):

In:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Preferences
```

delete `CtrlEnterSends` and restart Outlook. This will cause the dialog to display when Outlook is restarted.

Comment: No "Preferences" under "Outlook" folder

Comment: Thank you. I had to change the version (to the latest version folder I could see under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\`), but then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I just successfully tried this and can confirm it works 100%. Go to this registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Preferences
```

and change the `CtrlEnterSends` to `1` to have it send, to `0` to turn off sending (just dings if you try to send). You will need to restart Outlook for the changes to take effect. I was about to leave it at this, but then.

This was undocumented, and I just gave it a shot and it worked, but setting it to `2` re-enables the warning message.

Comment: This only works for outlook 2007 and 2010 and the question was for 2003. The 14.0 you use is only for 2010 but 2007 works on the same way.

Comment: That is true, it is only for 2007+, not for 2003

Comment: For the life of me, I thought we were talking about 2010 because I was also looking at another question regarding 2010 and something in tasks being grayed out. I will pull up a VM with office 2003 and try again. Thank you for not downvoting my reading slip.

Comment: I will leave my answer for anyone using 2007/2010.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick search on google and found it realy quick. You have to change or add the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook\DisabledShortcutKeysCheckBoxes
```

- String Value: `CtrlEnter`
- Value Data: `13,8`

---

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Word\DisabledShortcutKeysCheckBoxes
```

- String Value: `CtrlEnter`
- Value Data: `13,8`

These are the keys for Outlook 2003, change the `11.0` to `10.0` for Outlook 2002, or to `9.0` for 2000.

([Resource reference](http://www.slipstick.com/emo/2007/up071004.htm#.TfC8Qke0PFI))

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, but these registry keys disable the ctrl+enter shortcut. I have already tried these. I just need to re-enable the warning message when hitting ctrl+enter.

Comment: Have you tried this also with these values? I also found some other articles but with other values for the entries to disable the ctrl+enter.